# How do I find the exact meeting point of 2 lines?

Tags: modeling, snapping

**How do I find the *exact* meeting point of 2 lines?** I'd like to locate this place, and add a vertex on it. Preferably *no python.*

Here are some examples that the solution will need to solve for:

1. Tracing down 2 lines

   [image]
2. Tracing up one, down another 
   [image]
3. Tracing to a line 
   [image]

here is a

[image]

for testing.

<sub>P.S. If you have multiple solutions, please post them as different answers to help wit our site stats</sub>

Comment: @SixthOfFour I looked so hard... why do I miss these things so often!

Comment: I miss them too. But that specific question was the one that brought me here in the first place, so my memory of it was still clear.

Answer (score 1):

This works 100% with perpendiculars, still trying to find a method for non-perpendiculars.

- Enable edge snapping.
- turn the transform orientation to normal.
- make the pivot point median points.
- use the transform (should be Z) handles to drag the point to the edge.

Done